# Using Variables increases Scans and Logical Reads

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I can't understand this.  I have a query and if I hard code a number for a EntityType in the query, this is the IO statistics

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'FranchiseAgreement'. Scan count 1, logical reads 157, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Address'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5485, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'County'. Scan count 1, logical reads 126, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'State'. Scan count 0, logical reads 505, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Country'. Scan count 0, logical reads 488, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'City'. Scan count 0, logical reads 630, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ARTaxMasterfile'. Scan count 4, logical reads 36, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ELMasterfile'. Scan count 1, logical reads 205, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

nothing too bad.  Now all I am going to do is replace the hard coded number with a variable for readability

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ELMasterfile'. Scan count 1, logical reads 205, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
***Table 'FranchiseAgreement'. Scan count 539932, logical reads 1750032, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Address'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5485, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'County'. Scan count 0, logical reads 481, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'State'. Scan count 0, logical reads 505, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Country'. Scan count 0, logical reads 488, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'City'. Scan count 0, logical reads 630, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ARTaxMasterfile'. Scan count 4, logical reads 36, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

DECLARE @BalanceIdEL SMALLINT
SET @BalanceIdEL = 14

PRINT 'Version 5'
SELECT Stores.*, Tax.ARTaxMasterFileId
FROM
(   -- Get The Addres of Each Lease
    SELECT 
        E.LeaseNum
    ,   E.LeaseDate
    ,   A.CountryCode
    ,   A.StateProvCode
    ,   A.County
    ,   A.City
    FROM 
        ELMasterFile E
    INNER JOIN
        FranchiseAgreement F
        ON  E.EntityId = F.FranchiseID
        AND E.EntityType = 7
    INNER JOIN
        Address A
        ON  F.FranchiseNum = A.EntityId
        AND F.SatelliteNum = A.SatelliteNum
        AND A.EntityType = 5 -- Store
        AND A.AddressType = 3 -- Store Address  
    )  Stores
INNER JOIN 
    -- Get the Taxes at each Level, Country, State, County and City
    (SELECT A.*, C.CountryCode, '' AS StateProvCode, '' AS CountyName, '' AS CityName
    FROM ARTaxMasterFile A
    INNER JOIN
        COMMON.dbo.Country C
        ON A.ARTaxLevelTypeId = C.CountryId 
    where BalanceId = @BalanceIdEL
    and ARTaxLevelType = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.*, S.CountryCode, S.StateProvCode AS StateProvCode, '' AS CountyName, '' AS CityName
    FROM ARTaxMasterFile A
    INNER JOIN
        COMMON.dbo.State S
        ON A.ARTaxLevelTypeId = S.StateId 
    where BalanceId = @BalanceIdEL
    and ARTaxLevelType = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.*, C.CountryCode, C.StateProvCode AS StateProvCode,  C.CountyName AS CountyName, '' AS CityName
    FROM ARTaxMasterFile A
    INNER JOIN
        COMMON.dbo.County C
        ON A.ARTaxLevelTypeId = C.CountyId 
    where BalanceId = @BalanceIdEL
    and ARTaxLevelType = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.*, Country.CountryCode, State.StateProvCode AS StateProvCode,  County.CountyName AS CountyName, City.CityName AS CityName
    FROM ARTaxMasterFile A
    INNER JOIN
        COMMON.dbo.City City
        ON A.ARTaxLevelTypeId = City.CityId 
    INNER JOIN
        COMMON.dbo.County County
        ON City.CountyId = County.CountyId
    INNER JOIN
        COMMON.dbo.State State
        ON City.StateId = State.StateId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        COMMON.dbo.Country Country
        ON City.CountryId = Country.CountryId       
    where BalanceId = @BalanceIdEL
    and ARTaxLevelType = 4) Tax
    ON  (Stores.CountryCode = Tax.CountryCode
        AND Tax.StateProvCode = ''
        AND Tax.CountyName = ''
        AND Tax.CityName = '')
    OR 
        (Stores.CountryCode = Tax.CountryCode
        AND Stores.StateProvCode = Tax.StateProvCode 
        AND Tax.CountyName = ''
        AND Tax.CityName = '')
    OR 
        (Stores.CountryCode = Tax.CountryCode
        AND Stores.StateProvCode = Tax.StateProvCode 
        AND Stores.County = Tax.CountyName 
        AND Tax.CityName = '')
    OR 
        (Stores.CountryCode = Tax.CountryCode
        AND Stores.StateProvCode = Tax.StateProvCode 
        AND Stores.County = Tax.CountyName 
        AND Stores.City =Tax.CityName)
WHERE Tax.StartDate <= GETDATE()
AND Tax.StartDate > Stores.LeaseDate
```

The funniest thing is the parameter is not used on that table 
If I take out the Variable BalanceIdEL, and replace it with 14, the query is 2x faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the query optimizer doesn't realize that your variable is really a constant, and so picks a query plan with a table scan rather than an index lookup, since it believes the value is unknown. What does the query plan say? Maybe an index hint would forcew it to do the right thing.

I have mostly stopped using variables as constants for this reason - I now use constants with comments

Comment: +1, I have seen this too, and don't use @variables like this unless they are necessary because they change.  It's kind of like parameter sniffing, but without the variable being a parameter.